# Problemas desarrollo con android 7.x

Tags: android, android-studio, app

Recientemente desarrollé una aplicación en Android Studio, dicha aplicación no tiene ningún fallo al correr en android 6.0 o anterior, pero al instalarla en android 7.0 o más, la aplicación lanza un forzar cierre.

¿Alguna idea de que puede ser? ¿Alguien ha pasado por lo mismo?

En el LogCat me muestra lo siguiente:

```
10-16 14:16:22.265 16491-16491/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-16 14:16:22.317 16491-16498/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
10-16 14:16:22.317 16491-16498/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
10-16 14:16:22.317 16491-16498/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
10-16 14:16:22.330 16491-16491/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /mnt/expand/e68bdd3c-69bd-4bbd-9730-ac5869f3a246/app/com.richard.tusletrasolvidadas-1/lib/arm
10-16 14:16:22.348 16491-16491/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-16 14:16:22.350 16491-16491/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.richard.tusletrasolvidadas, PID: 16491
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/expand/e68bdd3c-69bd-4bbd-9730-ac5869f3a246/app/com.richard.tusletrasolvidadas-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/expand/e68bdd3c-69bd-4bbd-9730-ac5869f3a246/app/com.richard.tusletrasolvidadas-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5855)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5444)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5383)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/expand/e68bdd3c-69bd-4bbd-9730-ac5869f3a246/app/com.richard.tusletrasolvidadas-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/expand/e68bdd3c-69bd-4bbd-9730-ac5869f3a246/app/com.richard.tusletrasolvidadas-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5840)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5444) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5383) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

De antemano saludos.

Comment: Richard, busca el LogCat y publica el mensaje que te lanza cuando se cierra la app. Tambien tienes que agregar el codigo de la actividad donde te lanza el error para poder hacer un diagnostico.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Richard!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu pregunta actualmente es "muy amplia",debes modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad requerida en el sitio, esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Comment: @Einer

Ya coloque lo que me muestra el LogCat, ojala me puedas ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Por error `DexPathList` da a enteder que puede ser el liminte de los metodos del MultiDex.

Intenta lo siguiente. Modifca tu archivo `build.gradle` y agregale lo siguente:

```
android {

   defaultConfig {
      multiDexEnabled true
   }
}
```

En tu manifest:

```
<application

  android:name=".ClaseAplicacion">

</application>
```

Entonces crea una clase con el nombre `ClaseAplicacion` con lo siguente:

```
public class ClaseAplicacionextends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```